# Как отключить изменение размера экрана в Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

Есть Android девайc и небольшое веб приложение. Девайс будет подключен к телевизору, при отображении приложения на 42 дюймах 1080p, верстка подстраивается под мобильный интерфейс, в данном случае такой необходимости нет. Как отключить или изменить такое поведение.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть добавить кнопку "режим телевизора", по нажатию на которую ставится кука.
И будет идти проверка - если есть кука, то подключать дополнительный CSS, в котором отключается адаптивность.